# Problem connecting Upsilon 2000, How to setup with NUT

Tags: ups, usbhid, nut

I'm using Kubuntu 20.04.1 64 bit. To clarify I'm not trying to use this via network but directly via USB cable.

The UPS should be `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0001:0000 Fry's Electronics`

EDIT:

I found the [drivers list](https://networkupstools.org/stable-hcl.html) with, `"Various"       "ups"   "2"     "(Various USB)" "UPSilon 2000 software" "blazer_usb langid_fix=0x409"` and a little web search pointed to have the configuration like this and it connected.

---

```
[upsilon-2000]
driver = "blazer_usb"
port = auto
langid_fix="0x409"
desc="Upsilon 2000"
vendorid = "0001"
productid = "0000"
```

---

```
Network UPS Tools - UPS driver controller 2.7.4
Network UPS Tools - Megatec/Q1 protocol USB driver 0.12 (2.7.4)
Supported UPS detected with megatec protocol
Vendor information unavailable
No values provided for battery high/low voltages in ups.conf

Using 'guestimation' (low: 20.800000, high: 26.000000)!
Battery runtime will not be calculated (runtimecal not set)
```

Now I need to be able to configure it or is it already configured by default?

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# FINALDELAY - last sleep interval before shutting down the system
#
# On a master, upsmon will wait this long after sending the NOTIFY_SHUTDOWN
# before executing your SHUTDOWNCMD.  If you need to do something in between
# those events, increase this number.  Remember, at this point your UPS is 
# almost depleted, so don't make this too high.
#
# Alternatively, you can set this very low so you don't wait around when
# it's time to shut down.  Some UPSes don't give much warning for low
# battery and will require a value of 0 here for a safe shutdown.
#
# Note: If FINALDELAY on the slave is greater than HOSTSYNC on the master,
# the master will give up waiting for the slave to disconnect.

FINALDELAY 5
```

[upsmon.conf](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ssJBGmkBy4/)

I made a systemd service and this is the status shown. EDIT: I just needed nut-server.service

Message from system

```
Broadcast message from nut@carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 (somewhere) (Tue Nov 17 16:03:
Communications with UPS upsilon-2000@localhost established
```

---

```
[Unit]
Description=Upsilon monitor start

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=upsdrvctl start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

```
systemctl status ups-start.service 
● ups-start.service - Upsilon monitor start
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ups-start.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2020-11-17 15:38:41 AST; 3s ago
    Process: 7911 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/upsdrvctl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 7911 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

nov 17 15:38:37 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 upsdrvctl[7912]: Supported UPS detected with megatec protocol
nov 17 15:38:38 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 upsdrvctl[7912]: Vendor information unavailable
nov 17 15:38:38 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 upsdrvctl[7912]: No values provided for battery high/low voltages in ups.conf
nov 17 15:38:38 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 upsdrvctl[7912]: Using 'guestimation' (low: 20.800000, high: 26.000000)!
nov 17 15:38:38 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 upsdrvctl[7912]: Battery runtime will not be calculated (runtimecal not set)
nov 17 15:38:39 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 upsdrvctl[7911]: Network UPS Tools - UPS driver controller 2.7.4
nov 17 15:38:39 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 blazer_usb[7924]: Startup successful
nov 17 15:38:41 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 blazer_usb[7924]: Signal 15: exiting
nov 17 15:38:41 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 systemd[1]: ups-start.service: Succeeded.
nov 17 15:38:41 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 systemd[1]: Finished Upsilon monitor start.
```

This commands show:

```
upsdrvctl start
Network UPS Tools - UPS driver controller 2.7.4
Network UPS Tools - Megatec/Q1 protocol USB driver 0.12 (2.7.4)
Supported UPS detected with megatec protocol
Vendor information unavailable
No values provided for battery high/low voltages in ups.conf

Using 'guestimation' (low: 20.800000, high: 26.000000)!
Battery runtime will not be calculated (runtimecal not set)
```

---

```
sudo upsdrvctl stop
Network UPS Tools - UPS driver controller 2.7.4
Can't open /run/nut/blazer_usb-auto.pid: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I had NUT installed and configured many years ago. On my recent Ubuntu installation I found Gnome recognized the UPS as a battery when I connected it with the USB cable. I didn't install NUT. I think it shuts down the computer safely if there was no power and UPS battery gets critically low. I have not done any rigorous testing though. I don't know anything about KDE.

Comment: KDE has a battery monitor but it's doesn't work with my UPS @user68186

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was wondering if by relying on the Gnome battery monitor I was missing out something.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I haven't tested but this seems it's running properly. I would have to unplug my UPS and wait for 5 minutes. This is [/etc/nut/upsmon.conf](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/n5jFRHGqYb/)

Install NUT

```
apt install nut
```

Find out you USB IDs

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c084 Logitech, Inc. G203 Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c336 Logitech, Inc. Gaming Keyboard G213
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05a3:9331 ARC International Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0001:0000 Fry's Electronics 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Find out your
[Drivers](https://networkupstools.org/stable-hcl.html). Mine is listed as **blazer_usb langid_fix=0x409**

Configure `/etc/nut/ups.conf`

There is a command for this but for now it's doesn't say nothing about lang_fix part, maybe it's not needed anymore. `sudo nut-scanner`

```
[upsilon-2000]
driver = "blazer_usb"
port = auto
langid_fix="0x409"
desc="Upsilon 2000"
vendorid = "0001"
productid = "0000"
```

Edit nano **/etc/nut/nut.conf**

```
MODE=standalone
```

Start driver:

```
upsdrvctl start

NOTE: I made a Systemd service to run this command at boot
```

Enable service and start

```
systemctl enable nut-server.service
systemctl start nut-server.service
```

**You may need to reboot to make the server work properly.**

Check status

```
systemctl status nut-server
● nut-server.service - Network UPS Tools - power devices information server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nut-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-11-18 08:27:09 AST; 1h 4min ago
    Process: 997 ExecStart=/sbin/upsd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 998 (upsd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 19048)
     Memory: 1.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nut-server.service
             └─998 /lib/nut/upsd

nov 18 08:27:09 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 systemd[1]: Starting Network UPS Tools - power devices information server...
nov 18 08:27:09 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 upsd[997]: fopen /run/nut/upsd.pid: No such file or directory
nov 18 08:27:09 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 upsd[997]: listening on 127.0.0.1 port 3493
nov 18 08:27:09 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 upsd[997]: listening on ::1 port 3493
nov 18 08:27:09 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 upsd[997]: listening on 127.0.0.1 port 3493
nov 18 08:27:09 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 upsd[997]: listening on ::1 port 3493
nov 18 08:27:09 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 upsd[997]: Connected to UPS [upsilon-2000]: blazer_usb-upsilon-2000
nov 18 08:27:09 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 upsd[997]: Connected to UPS [upsilon-2000]: blazer_usb-upsilon-2000
nov 18 08:27:09 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 upsd[998]: Startup successful
nov 18 08:27:09 carlos-AB350-Gaming-3 systemd[1]: Started Network UPS Tools - power devices information server.
```

---

```
upsc upsilon-2000@localhost ups.status 2>&1 | grep -v '^Init SSL'
OL
```

For all the info

```
upsc upsilon-2000@localhost
Init SSL without certificate database
battery.charge: 100
battery.voltage: 27.20
battery.voltage.high: 26.00
battery.voltage.low: 20.80
battery.voltage.nominal: 24.0
device.type: ups
driver.name: blazer_usb
driver.parameter.langid_fix: 0x409
driver.parameter.pollinterval: 2
driver.parameter.port: auto
driver.parameter.productid: 0000
driver.parameter.synchronous: no
driver.parameter.vendorid: 0001
driver.version: 2.7.4
driver.version.internal: 0.12
input.current.nominal: 15.0
input.frequency: 59.9
input.frequency.nominal: 60
input.voltage: 118.2
input.voltage.fault: 118.2
input.voltage.nominal: 120
output.voltage: 118.2
ups.beeper.status: enabled
ups.delay.shutdown: 30
ups.delay.start: 180
ups.load: 20
ups.productid: 0000
ups.status: OL
ups.type: offline / line interactive
ups.vendorid: 0001
```

[source](https://zackreed.me/installing-nut-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

I used the below in ups.conf and it works well:

```
[myups]
        driver = nutdrv_qx
        port = auto
        desc = "My UPS"
        pollfreq = 1
```

Comment: chech the command "sudo nut scanner"